# Whats the best way to use JMS for this requirement

Tags: java, jms

I need a setup where messages can be transmitted to a queue or topic which is listened to by 2 or more servers.

The consumer is a specific client who will access one of those 2 servers and it is not known ahead of time which server the client will check from. The message will have an ID on it which correlates to the correct client.

There may be multiple messages at any time waiting to be consumed by various clients accessing these servers.

How can I accomplish this? Queue, topic? point-to-point or publish subscribe? What exact setup would do this trick?

Here's another way to look at the scenario: imagine multiple towns which have a community mail box. The residents of these towns do not have specific addresses rather they are constantly moving around between the towns. Someone needs to send a message to another person, so they create the mail and it gets copied and routed to each town's mailbox waiting to be received. When the right person checks and finds the message addressed to him, the message is consumed and destroyed on all the other mailboxes ensuring the same message is not read again.

So the JMS queue or topic is this mailbox, and the clients connecting to these servers (which specifically are web servers in a clustered environment) are the people. Multiple messages addressed to different people can exist at the same time.

Whats the best way to do this using JMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to address messages to specific clients, you can use consumer-side selectors, here's a round trip example:

## Server Sends

```
 QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
 queueSender.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
 TextMessage message = queueSession.createTextMessage("Hello John!");
 message.setObjectProperty("ToAddress", "John-123");
 queueSender.send(message);
```

## Consumer Receives

```
 QueueConnection queueConn = connFactory.createQueueConnection();
 QueueSession queueSession = queueConn.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
 QueueReceiver queueReceiver = 
    queueSession.createReceiver(queue, "ToAddress = 'John-123'");
 queueConn.start();
 TextMessage message = (TextMessage) queueReceiver.receive();
```

The client creates a `queueReceiver` using the selector `ToAddress=John-123`, so only messages that match that selector are delivered to that client; other messages go to different consumers based on their selector.

If queuereceiver 'John-123' is not connected, any messages addressed to him simply accumulate in the queue. If you want to receive messages in real time, the receiver needs to be connected, always. To check for messages intermittently (sort of like checking email a few times a day), there's not too much overhead associated with creating a receiver, checking for messages, then disconnecting, however, avoid doing that repeatedly (1000's of times, or more); if that's the case, just keep the receiver connected all the time.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think the problem with this though is the checking of the queue may happen from either server, at any time. This solution seems to setup a fixed queue listener on all the servers involved, which then stays listening all the time, is that correct? Or were you thinking when the client accesses one of the servers and checks for a message it sets up and destroys the queue listener each time? Is that a lot of overhead though to keep doing that?

Comment: Updated answer above: If you're using ActiveMq, WebLogic, or WebSphere JMS, you can set up many servers, all with the same queue, it wouldn't matter which server the receiver connected to; JMS guarantees exactly once processing for queue-based messages. Are you using standalone receivers, or MDB's?